# Returning Successful ping but after a fatal error

Tags: php, search, solr, fatal-error

I am using the [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) library.And I have this code:

```
<?php
namespace Solarium;
use Solarium;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require(__DIR__.'\solarium\init.php');

htmlHeader();

// check solarium version available
echo 'Solarium library version: ' . Client::VERSION . ' - ';

// create a client instance

$config = array(
    'endpoint' => array(
        'localhost' => array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 3306,
            'path' => '/solarium/',
        )
    )
);

$client = new Solarium\Client($config);

// create a ping query
$ping = $client->createPing();

// execute the ping query
try {
    $result = $client->ping($ping);
    echo 'Ping query successful';
    echo '<br/><pre>';
    var_dump($result->getData());
    echo '</pre>';
} catch (Solarium\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Ping query failed';
}

htmlFooter();
```

Well.It sorta works.

It gives me this:

```
Solarium library version: 3.0.0 - Ping query successful


    Fatal error:  Uncaught Solarium\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Solr JSON response could not be decoded in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\solarium\solarium\library\Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result.php:158
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\ping4.php(34): Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result->getData()
    #1 {main}
      thrown in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.0.0RC7-\apache2\htdocs\vendor\solarium\solarium\library\Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result.php on line 158
```

So The *ping* was successful.but I get a **fatal** error after a successful ping.

What am I *supposed* to get? And what am i doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: what is the path you use to request solr ?

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI `'path' => '/solarium/'`

Comment: you have # in the path ?

Comment: something like /solarium/#/ ?

Comment: no which #?I dont get

Comment: No I do not have

Comment: If you manually execute a ping query on your solr server, what is the response?

Comment: Which solr server?